# Get an array element from an array in a json attribute of a jsonb column

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I am using postgres database and I have an array inside a json attribute in a jsonb column and I need to get the first element of that array. The jsonb_column structure is like the below:

```
"IndustryCode": {
"Code": "111110",
"Keys": [
  "11",
  "111",
  "111110"
],}
```

So far I can get all the query elements by issuing the query below

```
select jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column->'IndustryCode'->'Keys' ) from myindustry;
```

How can I query to get the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first element, there is no need to unnest the whole array. the `->` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) also accepts an integer which specifies the array index.

```
select jsonb_column -> 'IndustryCode' -> 'Keys' ->> 0 
from myindustry;
```

Note I used `->>` to return the value as `text` not as `jsonb`

Comment: Thank you so much for you help @a_horse_with_no_name